# Extract flat files contents into individual words and store into database

Tags: java, python, xml

I've done a lot of internet searching to find some information to no avail.. Hopefully you can help me..

I want to be able to use a flat file, with normal content (i.e. full english sentences, paragraphs etc), extract each word and store each word individually, one word per row, in a SQL database (doesn't matter if there are spaces but characters such as apostrophes can be kept in)

I then want to have a HTML page with code to access this DB and output the text to the user one word at a time, essentially 'writing' the inputted files text word-by-word on the web page.

This is just a coding exercise but I am frustrated as I know the what but not the how.. I am not sure where to start. Please note some of these files can be quite big ~ 20,000 words so there may be a performance element to consider to any solution.

TL;DR: I want to extract individual words from a text file with normal everyday sentences into a SQL DB that I can retrieve from a HTML page.

Comment: Just to have more information - why are you storing these words? Do you want to make a dictionary, or find the most commonly used words?

Comment: Also, when asking your questions, you should choose just one part that you want to ask about - i.e. are you have trouble with splitting the strings, reading in input files, adding them to the database, etc.? This will help keep answers brief and more easily understandable. See my answer below for different parts that you can ask more specific questions about.

Answer (score 0):

Simple read & split exercise

```
    with open(<filename>) as f:
        dd = {}
        for ln in f:
            wds = ln.strip().split()
            for word in wds:
                dd[word] = 1 # need something for value

    for wkey in dd:
        <insert into db>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, before you start you should choose just one programming language. Since you seem like you are a beginner I would highly recommend Python over Java, but it depends on if you're required to use any particular language by an employer/professor/etc.

Also just to point out, this is also a very BIG task that you've chosen. I'll try to break it down into parts for you, but I recommend starting with just one of these parts before you move on, and make sure it works on your local machine before you try putting it on the web.

First you need to use something read in your file, preferably line by line. A method similar to FileReader/BufferedReader in Java or the open(), readlines() functions in Python will do these. I would also check out the tutorials online on file handling for whichever of these two languages you're going to use. The [Python one is here](http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html). Practice this with a test file or a small section of your real file before you start working on your real input files.

When you start processing the lines from the file, I would recommend splitting them into individual words using a string split function on spaces or on any punctuation, such as `,.!?"`. This way you'll pull out the individual words from the each line in the file.

Next, you'll want to choose a database API for the appropriate programming language. I used [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/) but there is also [MySQLDB](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) for Python. In Java there is [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

You'll need to then build your database on a server somewhere, preferably on the same server as your HTML page for ease of connection. You'll want to practice connecting to your database and adding sample rows before you start trying to process your real input files.

You can't have normal HTML access the database directly - you'll need to use a coding language like Python for that. I've never used Java for webpages, but with Python you'll simply output text and tell the server to display it as the webpage. This will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import otherstuffhere

## Must have this header to tell browser how to handle this output
## and must be printed first
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")

## Connect to database here

## Your code to display words from the database goes below here
print (myfield1)
```

Also remember that when you output your text, you'll need to add all the HTML tags to the normal text output. For example, when printing each word, you'll need to add `<p>` or `<br>` to end each line, because although the Python print() function will automatically add a line break, this doesn't translate to a line break in HTML. For example:

```
print ("My word list is: <br>")
for word in dbOutputList:
    print (word)
    print ("<br>")
```

After that the REAL fun/crying begins, but you should work on the above before you move on.